# Force IE9 to load uncached location after redirection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, browser-cache

We recently geolocalized our site, and it now detects the user preferred language set in the browser options. By example, if you have France French set first, you'll be redirected to the France homepage (/fr-fr) using an HTTP301.

The problems is if you want to set get back to the English US homepage, at the root (/), IE9 has in cache that it's a redirection and request directly to the redirected URL. At first I tough that it was server side but using Fiddler2 I found out that it was IE jerking. I've tried to add a timestamp to the URL but it doesn't change a thing.

Is there any mean to force IE to load the page without rewiring the request? I've tried document.location and it doesn't work.

The website is at www.sherweb.com if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 302 redirection and it should do the trick.